# What specifications we need to create a ROS-Mirror?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone:

In my university are interested in creating a ROS mirror in our servers.

Let us know that specifications need.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58279/what-specifications--we-need-to-create-a-ros-mirror?/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to create a mirror is here: http://answers.ros.org/question/10010/create-a-rosorg-wiki-mirror/

For specifications most any webserver will do if you're only planning to use it for a small group of people.  You'll need many gigabytes of space.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0